# How to add SSL certificate inside binary file?

Tags: rust

I have this small working project in my local network where two computers send messages through WebSocket over HTTPS. The project is compiled in Rust standalone binary file. This file requires an SSL certificate, so I need to put it inside after already been compiled. Is it possible? Also, is it possible to update it if already part of the binary file?

Comment: Hello, the thing you are trying to do is reverse engineering. I don't know what's used on Windows/Linux but in android, we use Frida so there should be similar tools that do dynamic instrumentation. I think bpf should provide a solution.  If you have source code I would recommend patching it in source code otherwise things can get complicated.

Comment: Why do you need that ? Putting the key inside the binary is not a good idea.

Comment: I plan to expand my network. If I need to configure SSL certificates for each computer would be hard. Also, SSL certificates expire and need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a way to do this that doesn't involve modifying compiled binaries (if you can access the key at compile time you can do `include_str!` and if you have file system access you can read it from disk at run time), but there is a fairly hacky way to do this if you must:

1. Put a dummy key in a `const` or `static`, and read from that in the binary.
2. Replace the dummy key with the real key in the binary, **making sure that you don't change the size of the binary**.
3. Run the modified binary, it will use the new key now.

This works because you can modify strings in binaries and it usually won't cause any issues as long as don't change the size of the binary. But keep in mind that the compiler doesn't expect the compiled binaries to be modified, so make sure that there aren't compiler optimisations that fail when the value of the key is changed.

For example, put this in `x.rs`

```rust
const KEY: &str = "PRIVATEKEYEXAMPLE";
fn main() {
    println!("{}", KEY);
}
```

and run:

```bash
$ rustc x.rs
$ sed s/PRIVATEKEYEXAMPLE/REALLYPRIVATEKEYY/g < x > y # replace the string in the binary
$ chmod +x y
$ ./y
REALLYPRIVATEKEYY
```

Comment: Thanks. At first sight, looks good. Unfortunately, it is not working on Mac OS, returning error:`sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`
I am sorry I should say that computers are running Mac OS. Looks like `sed` is working differently on Mac OS.